# How to use argparse parse_args to parse arguments as a string in python?

Tags: python, argparse

My original code like the following works well with command line calls. However, is there a way that I could parse a list of arguments as a string in Python?

Example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()
```

And you call:

```
python test.py <args like --a 1 --b 2 ...>
```

Then if I have a string `s` which is the `args` list above, is there a way I could get that parsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the string into a list and pass it to `parse_args`:

```
parser.parse_args(s.split())
```

Or if the string contains shell-like syntax such as quotes and escape characters, use `shlex.split` to split the string:

```
import shlex
parser.parse_args(shlex.split(s))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting an error like this: ArgumentError: argument --data_dir: conflicting option string: --data_dir, where `data_dir` is one of the arguments I defined. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: There is another option you define that has the same prefix as `--data_dir` so it's considered conflicting. You can fix this by naming the option something else.